# iPhone ABContact address book sorting.

Tags: iphone

How can I sort my address book by first name. I'm using the ABContact class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get an array of all the contacts with the method :

```
CFArrayRef ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople (
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook
);
```

Then you can create a mutable version of the array using :

```
CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(
                                          kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          CFArrayGetCount(people),
                                          people
                                  );
```

And you can sort this array with :

```
CFArraySortValues(
        peopleMutable,
        CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(peopleMutable)),
        (CFComparatorFunction) ABPersonComparePeopleByName,
        (void*) ABPersonGetSortOrdering()
);
```

You have a fully documented sample in the [Address Book Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1)

Hope this helps,
Vincent